# Frameworks for Common tasks using Jquery, Java and Datastore - Login/Logout and User Fields

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, jquery-ui, frameworks

I am looking for common framework for logging in, logging out, changing profile information and other common tasks such as managing sessions etc.

The common framework should be using jquery to give web 2.0 avatar and if possible using Google datastore in it backend.

Is there a framework like that?

I understand that framework is more application specific but a framework would help avoid repetitive tasks.

Thanks.

Comment: All of those things are easy to do with just Java Servlets and the App Engine APIs. Why do you want a different framework?

Comment: I found some templates on themeforest to choose my taste and wrote backend code.

Answer (score 0):

Am I reading you correctly, you want a 'javascript' framework that uses jquery to do all that in the browser app?

Perhaps http://plugins.jquery.com/ has what you need although my guess is that you'll find that most of the functionality you need is server-side java/appengine as Nick stated.